# C inserting string into char pointer

Tags: c, string

Hi all I trying to assign `string` into a `char *` pointer. Below is how I am doing but I am getting this **warning:** `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.`

What is the correct why to deal with strings in C ?

```
char* protoName = "";

if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==0)
    *protoName = "HOPOPT";  
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==1)
    *protoName = "ICMP";    
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==2)
    *protoName = "IGMP";    
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==3)
    *protoName = "IGMP";    
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==4)
    *protoName = "IGMP";

char all[500];

sprintf(all,"IPv4','%s'",* protoName);
```

Comment: *protoName is the same as protoName[0]. A single character will not hold a string. So use protoName = "HOPOPT";

Comment: @So then which is the best way to change it

Comment: *protoName equals protoName[0]. That's a single character. You want to change the place protoName points to. So say protoName = "abcd";

Comment: So the first char* protoName define it as a pointer to list of char is it ? IT can be single or multiple char right ?

Comment: `char *protoName` defines a pointer to a character, called `protoName`. There's no such thing as a "list of char". The pointer can point to a single `char`, it can point to an array of `char`, it can point to a string and for all those combinations, it can be pointing to memory on stack or the heap. It can also point to junk, but that's an answer for another question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to change which string literal `protoName` points to, you just need to change

```
*protoName = "HOPOPT";
```

to

```
protoName = "HOPOPT";
```

`*protoName =` attempts to write to the first character pointed to by `protoName`.  This won't work in your case as `protoName` points to a string literal which cannot be modified.

You also need to change your `sprintf` call to

```
sprintf(all,"IPv4','%s'", protoName);
```

The `%s` format specifier signals that you'll be passing a pointer to a nul-terminated `char` array.  `*protoName` gives you the character code of the first character pointed to by `protoName`; `sprintf` doesn't know this so would treat that character code as the address of the array to read from.  You don't own this memory so the effects of reading from it would be undefined; a crash would be likely.

As an aside, if you had a writeable `char` array and wanted to change its contents, you'd need to use `strcpy` to copy a new array of chars into it.

Comment: How about me putting to the sprintf is it correct to put * protoName

Comment: @user2711681 I'd missed that.  I've updated my answer to explain that this line needs to change too

Comment: @So what is the writeable char array ? Isnt this *protoName a dynamic pointer to a list of char ?

Comment: A writeable char array is one where you've allocated your own memory rather than just a pointer to someone else's memory.  `char str[20]` or `char* str = malloc(20)` would give you a writeable array with space for 20 chars.

Comment: @user2711681 No, `protoName` is a pointer to a string literal (which cannot be modified and should be treated as constant that is empty). `*protoName` is an attempt to dereference the pointer `protoName` and will give you the first thing that `protoName` points to. In this case, a `char` which will be `0`. I won't pussy-foot around: if you plan on working with C you **MUST** understand the differences between arrays, pointers and strings, what the address-of '&' and dereference '*' operators do and how memory allocation works.

Comment: @NikBougalis I am learning and getting very confuse among them when it involves pointer. Array I am quite clear as its fixed.

Comment: @user2711681 It can be confusing at first. Don't get discouraged. See my comment in another answer.

Comment: @Thank you for encouragement but in my case as waht simon have written is it correct now to use?

Comment: I included examples with sprintf, strcpy, and how to get rid of the long ugly if statement. Hope if helps.

Comment: @Simonc are you suggesting to change to writeable char rather than chat * as now what I am doing ?

Comment: @user2711681 No.  I think your code is fine (indeed more correct) if you stick with `char*` plus the changes I suggest (everything before the aside).  The aside was an extra bit of information I thought you might find useful in future; I didn't intend for you to make use of it for your current program.

Comment: @user814064 so the first index is 0 or 1 in your case ? You answer looks good

Comment: @Simonc how about the answer give by user2711681 is it correct to use that ?

Comment: Erm... you are @user2711681 :-).  If you meant user814064, the code in `protoNameFromPktId` is a valid approach.  There is nothing wrong with your `if` / `else if` approach however.  Indeed, you code is slightly better at present as it copes with `h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto > 4` (by printing a blank protocol name).  The `protoNameFromPktId` function would need to be modified to handle this.

Comment: Sorry yes user814064 answer. What to modify it to handle > 4 and cause I find mine will become very long if I need to cater for all the protocols ?  How about speed ? Which is better ?

Comment: Simonc I think I need to write free(protoName) at the end right ?

Comment: @user2711681 No.  You only need to call `free` for pointers allocated using `malloc`.  You haven't done any dynamic allocation so are spared the hassle of manually freeing memory.

Comment: @So can I can conclude that only if I use malloc then need the free say if I plan to use user814064 method how to handle those exception? What is your advice is it to keep with my if-else method or change to this method because I am going to do for more protocols not just these 4

Comment: You're correct that about use of `malloc`/`free`.  You'll be fine to stick with your `if`/`else` method for now.  Or change to a `switch(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto)`

Comment: @user2711681 If you really, really want to use the other method add if `(id >= sizeof(protoName) / sizeof(protoName[0])) return "";` to it.

Comment: Yes, you'll need many lines.  Execution will jump immediately to the correct `case` however so don't worry about this being inefficient.  (You probably shouldn't worry about performance at all; the compiler will probably optimise things appropriately)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using constants, then simply reassign the pointer, not the contents:

```
const char* protoName = "";
if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==0)
    protoName = "HOPOPT";    
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==1)
    protoName = "ICMP";  
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==2)
    protoName = "IGMP";  
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==3)
    protoName = "IGMP";  
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==4)
    protoName = "IGMP";
```

Comment: @Why I need to define as *protoNAme but assign is just protoNAme what is the difference ?

Comment: Because that's how C works. It is the same as your initial line, `char *a = b;`, and on every other operation you don't need to add `char *` all the time. It's exactly the same as `int x = 1; x = 2;` -- for your string, the type is `char *`.

Comment: @user2711681 You are confused because the `*` operator has three meanings in C: it can mean "multiply", it can mean "declare as pointer" or it can mean "dereference pointer" and stumbling on the fact that strings are handled "specially" in C.

Comment: @Yes u are right I am confuse with * especially in the pointer area ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * protoNameFromPktId(int id) {
    static char* protoName[] = { "HOPOPT", "ICMP", "IGMP", "IGMP","IGMP"};
    return protoName[id];
}

main() {
   printf("%s\n", protoNameFromPktId(2));
   char all[500];
   sprintf(all,"%s", protoNameFromPktId(2));
   strcpy(all, protoNameFromPktId(2));
}
```

Comment: @What is the first index 0 or 1 in this case ? What is the speed difference between this and if else ?

Comment: It is zero. It matches your if - else.

Comment: @how about efficiency in comparison to using if else ?

Comment: It doesn't have to test anything over and over again. It's just one lookup. In the look run -- equally efficient -- just clearer and easier to change.

Comment: The if else is slower than the array indexing, but putting the array index in a function call probably loses any advantage.  Maybe the compiler will inline that, and maybe it won't, but you can define the array in your function, as given (make is const static char *protoName[], though) and using protoName[extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto] is just as easy and self-explanatory as protoNameFromPktId(extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto).

Comment: PS: unsigned id=extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto; and then char *proto=(id < sizeof protoName / sizeof *protoName) ? protoName[id] : ""; will guard against invalid or unexpected protocol values--just as your if/else if chain does now.

Comment: So what you are saying is have the static char* protoName[] = { "HOPOPT", "ICMP", "IGMP", "IGMP","IGMP"}; define on one line then just call this rite unsigned id=extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto;char *proto=(id < sizeof protoName / sizeof *protoName) ? protoName[id] : ""; Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this:-

```
protoName = "HOPOPT";
```

instead of

```
*protoName = "HOPOPT";
```

So change like :-

```
char* protoName = "";
  if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==0)
  protoName = "HOPOPT";    
  else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==1)
  protoName = "ICMP";  
  else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==2)
  protoName = "IGMP";  
  else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==3)
  protoName = "IGMP";  
  else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==4)
  protoName = "IGMP";

  char all[500];
    sprintf(all,"IPv4','%s'",* protoName);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that I can see is that you dont bind memory for the strings, so you have to use `malloc` or better use [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) function that allocates memory automatically. because if you assigned big strings then you should have a problem.
The problem with the warning answered by the others, so is ok. plz correct me if I'm wrong.

```
char* protoName;
if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==0){
   protoName = strdup("HOPOPT");    
}
else if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto==1){
  protoName = strdup("ICMP");  
...
char all[500];
sprintf(all,"IPv4','%s'",* protoName);
free(protoName);
```

Comment: Don't forget `free(protoName);`.  However what is the point in copying a constant string?

Comment: Note that you'd also need a final `else` block with this approach to avoid the possibility of an uninitialised `protoName` being dereferenced by `sprintf`.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to do `char *protoName = ""; protoName = "ICMP";` just as long as you understand what it is the code does, what `protoName` points to and how it can used.

Comment: Why is the free needed here ?